# Flickering Disaster in some photos with A7III

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, adobe-lightroom

I made a disaster with Sony A7iii silent shoot, I have a huge flicker in some photos. [image]
Is there any way to fix it a little at least? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: related https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59454/how-can-one-correct-intensity-flicker-due-to-ac-line-frequency

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be difficult to remove these lines completely, however there is an approach which can reduce them to an extent. The result is not perfect though.

I used GIMP and the G'MIC plugin's Fourier Transform filter to suppress the stripe pattern, but if you can find a Fourier Transform plugin* for Photoshop, you could also do something similar.

Here's the before and after

[image]

I also did a little extra retouching with the Clone tool to remove some of the artefacts around the subject which the process can cause. I'm sure with some extra time and care you can make a better job than me - I did this very quickly just as an example.

Here's how I edited the Fourier Transform image, by painting over the brighter spots and lines (leaving the central cross and bright centre) before reversing the transform. The screencapture is speeded up to show you what I did.

[image]

***Edit:** I found a [plugin for Photoshop](http://ft.rognemedia.no/) which could be used similarly. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Hmm... maybe frequency separation would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Actually this kind of problem is really hard to solve in Photoshop without affecting the quality but I will try to do my best.

If we are talking about only this picture

At first duplicte your original layer to use in further or prevent any accident.

1. Change mode to lab color to get different color space in Photoshop
2. Make sure that you selected all channels in channels tab (Lab is the main channel if I remember well)
3. Use surface blur from filters and find the optimum values in blur amount and threshold.

After these steps flickers will be better than before. At that point you need to separate parts from image like display behind man, shirt, wall behind display and desk. At that point, you need to use heal and little blur filters to have almost-same colors. I can't guarantee that it will help you 100% but at least there will be less flicker than this image.